# .FILL doesn't working on NULL guid

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I've a table like this structure:

[image]

now, sometimes, the field: `resources_guid` could be null, in particular if is NULL I set a value of 0. I'm trying to fill all records in the table using this technique:

```
Dim local_ds As New DataSet
Dmi query = "SELECT * FROM tables"
MyAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(query, my connection)
MyAdapter.Fill(local_ds)
```

but when the `.Fill` method is executed I get this error message:

> Guid must contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"

How I can solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please apply the following design for all guid fields:

[GUID] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL

Sample GUID: '2564B262-B3B9-E511-97AD-00155D022706'

You can get value from this function listed below :
SELECT NEWID()

Hope this helps, good luck :)

Comment: You mean this: `resources_guid` char(36) UNIQUE NOT NULL, ?

Comment: I mean: resources_guid [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL, there is a type for guid=> uniqueidentifier.